Revoke grants for dynamic table for owner
I have a use case where we need to grant ownership permission in dev schemas for developers. For some reason, they can also create dynamic tables, tasks, etc. which I thought required extra grants before they could actually use it (or maybe someone granted those permissions from admin groups)
Here is an example
schema - dev.foo and role - developer_role
developer_role has ownership grants to operate on dev.foo so they can create views/tables and develop logic before they push to production but they should not be able to create dynamic tables, tasks, etc which can increase the cost. While we want to have developer_role maintain the same permissions as the schema owner, we want to limit the capability to create objects that can incur extra costs.
I tried revoking grants like
revoke create dynamic table on schema dev.foo from role developer_role;

They are still able to create these dynamic tables and my suspicion is it is because they have ownership grants assigned to that role.

If you own a DB/schema you can create any object type in that database/schema.
If you want to restrict what your developers can do in a schema then you’d need to create a role that only has the privileges you want them to have - and is not the schema owner.
